# How to install apache module in docker container at the correct location

Tags: apache, docker, debian, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I have the following docker file:

```
FROM wodby/apache:2.4
MAINTAINER NAME EMAIL
ENV http_proxy 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.de:80'
ENV https_proxy 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80'
ENV APP_ROOT="/var/www/html" \
    APACHE_DIR="/usr/local/apache2"

WORKDIR /usr/local/apache2

USER root
RUN ls


RUN set -x \
    && apk add apache-mod-auth-kerb


CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

My intention is to add the apache-mod-auth-kerb module to my container.
Base Image is alpine but wodby/apache inherits from wodby/http which is Debian.

Somehow the module is installed under /usr/lib/apache2 but the apache in wodby/apache seems to load its modules from /usr/local/apache2/modules.

I don't think the solution is to move the module per cp or symlink?

Here are the links to the base dockerfiles:
https://github.com/wodby/httpd
https://github.com/wodby/apache

How can I make sure that the module and config are put in the correct location? I think the problem might be the difference between the used Linux distros. 
Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docker-library/httpd](https://github.com/docker-library/httpd) (Maintained by Docker) supports alpine and Debian based images.

Since wodby/httpd is forked from docker-library/httpd, you can see files Debian related Dockerfile but they only support alpine based images as per the README.md file.

Even images woby/apache are alpine based.

For modules, you can create a conf file as shown below

**mod_auth_kerb.conf**

```
LoadModule auth_kerb_module /usr/lib/apache2/mod_auth_kerb.so
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM wodby/apache:2.4
MAINTAINER NAME EMAIL
ENV http_proxy 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.de:80'
ENV https_proxy 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80'
ENV APP_ROOT="/var/www/html" \
    APACHE_DIR="/usr/local/apache2"

WORKDIR /usr/local/apache2

USER root
RUN ls


RUN set -x \
    && apk add apache-mod-auth-kerb

COPY mod_auth_kerb.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/conf.d/mod_auth_kerb.conf
```

You can check them

```
bash-4.4# httpd -M | grep auth_kerb_module
   auth_kerb_module (shared)
```

Comment: If already replaced the > above with >> but it is somehow not working. The line doesnt get added. I even tried to copy a httpd.conf over to the container but it fails with. 
`(7/7) Installing apache-mod-auth-kerb (5.4-r5)  
Executing busybox-1.29.3-r10.trigger  
OK: 133 MiB in 85 packages  
Removing intermediate container c772d90792b0  
 ---> ab362aa46f43  
Step 10/11 : COPY httpd.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf  
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder085042809/httpd.conf: no such file or directory  
`

Comment: I have edited the answer with copying new conf file. This is much simpler as it removes the dependency of editing the httpd.conf

Comment: Works correct right now - run in that Windows glitch. The file was created with CRLF in PHPStorm. Converting to LF fixed this.